# iOS App Crash around setcontentoffset any tips?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash-reports

According to Flurry, I have a high frequency of app crashes around `uiscrollview/uitableview setcontentoffset`.

Here is the details of it, anyone has faced something similar?

```
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39b80f46 _objc_msgSend + 5
    1   UIKit                               0x2f915795 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 632
    2   UIKit                               0x2f9c02c5 -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 412
    3   UIKit                               0x2fba3b5f -[UIScrollView _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1466
    4   UIKit                               0x2f9c6671 -[UIScrollView _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 452
    5   UIKit                               0x2f9c64a7 -[UIScrollView _stopScrollingNotify:pin:] + 30
    6   UIKit                               0x2f9c6463 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 30
    7   UIKit                               0x2f8f8f47 -[UIView dealloc] + 382
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x2c36526d _CFRelease + 600
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x2c37c3bd -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 148
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39b8ed5f  + 166
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39b8f1a9  + 404
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x2c3703a9 __CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x2c4222ef  + 1518
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x2c370621 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x2c370433 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x336d80a9 _GSEventRunModal + 136
    17  UIKit                               0x2f95a809 _UIApplicationMain + 1440
    18  aNews                               0x00053b1b __mh_execute_header + 23323
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a0f4aaf  + 2
```

Comment: Update your question with the actual error message in the crash report.

Comment: Turn on zombies in your build scheme and you are likely to get an error message at run-time that says some object received a message after being deallocated.  That information can help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you do the `setContentOffset` not on main thread. Or maybe some other method is in the background, then when it executes it's not on the main thread. Everything should be done on the main thread when it relates to UI. Try it on the main thread and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Your original answer, even if correct, was extremely hard to read and understand. I've tried to clean it up, but please take more care in the future.

Comment: @bgilham OK thanks for your suggestion, will be much more readable.